# How to group different rewrite rules in nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to have a lighter code for one of my NGINX configurations. I need to write the following four lines in only one (if possible!):

```
location /en/contact {
    rewrite ^/.* https://$server_name/contact permanent;
}

location /en/quality {
    rewrite ^/.* https://$server_name/quality permanent;

location /de/contact {
    rewrite ^/.* https://$server_name/contact permanent;
}

location /de/quality {
    rewrite ^/.* https://$server_name/quality permanent;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "lighter"? The prefix location (you have now) is probably most efficient. You could use a regular expression which would be less efficient - but also less typing.

Comment: My goal is to have the minimum typing. How could I use a regular expression with this case? I am pretty new in this... Efficiency is a point... I would like to compare with the two versions.

Answer (score 0):

Using minimal typing, you could use a `rewrite` statement outside of any location block:

```
rewrite ^/(en|de)/(contact|quality) https://$server_name/$2 permanent;
```

If the scheme and server name does not change, the second parameter can be replaced with just `/$2`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Alternatively, you could use a regular expression `location` block:

```
location ~ ^/(en|de)/(contact|quality) {
    return 301 https://$server_name/$2;
}
```

Same as above, regarding the scheme and server name. Note that the evaluation order for regular expression location blocks is significant - the first rule that matches wins. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!